# How to use pipe (" | ") in PHP exec?

Tags: php, command, exec

I can use CMD to execute two commands at the same time using:

```
command1 | command2
```

In PHP, I assumed it should work, but it doesn't:

```
Shell_exec("command1 | command2 ");
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: use `Shell_exec("command1 & command2 ");`

Comment: Doesn't this require a double pipe, as in "||"?

Answer (score 9):

Try to add braces:

```
shell_exec("(command1 | command2)");
```

There is [a comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#39969) in the PHP documentation that does some I/O-redirection with `popen`.

Answer (score 2):

## Try [disabling *safe mode*](https://serverfault.com/questions/444328/how-can-i-disable-safe-mode-for-php-on-web-server).

---

#### For [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

> **Note**:
>   This function **is disabled** when PHP is running in *safe mode*.

---

#### For [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php):

> **Note**: When *safe mode* is enabled, you can **only execute files within** the `safe_mode_exec_dir`. For practical reasons, it is currently not allowed to have `..` components in the path to the executable.
>
> **Warning**:
>   With *safe mode* enabled, **the command string is escaped** with `escapeshellcmd()`. Thus, `echo y | echo x` becomes `echo y \| echo x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling safe mode.

> Safe mode will be removed in PHP 6.0.0.

It has already been removed from Php.ini

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me a lot.  Try to add brackets:

```
shell_exec("(command1 | command2)");
```

There is a comment in the PHP documentation that does some I/O-redirection with popen:

```
shell_exec("(openssl s_client -servername {$domain_name} -connect {$domain_name}:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | grep notAfter | sed -e s#notAfter=##)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap it in another command:

```
shell_exec( 'cmd /c "command1 | command2"' );
```

Answer (score -5):

You could try `;` instead of `|` in your command.
Referencing to [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#65627) comment at php.net.