# PHP: How to get the IP address of a specific VLAN

Tags: php, bash, awk

Background: A page should display SNMP data from various devices in a mgmt vlan, to loop through all IP addresses in the network. I need to know the IP address/network, the interface is on.

In [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) this works perfectly:

```
/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0.1100 | /usr/bin/awk  '/global/ { $2=substr($2, 1, length($2)-7); print $2 }'
```

But in PHP I can't find a way to get the IP address/network of the mgmt vlan. I tried:

```
$mgmtiface = shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/awk '$3 == 1100 {print $1}' /proc/net/vlan/config");
$mgmtnet = shell_exec("/sbin/ip addr show dev $mgmtiface | /usr/bin/awk  '/global/ { $2=substr($2, 1, length($2)-7); print $2 }' ");
```

But PHP doesn't like [pipe in shell_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733918/how-to-use-pipe-in-php-exec).

How do I solve this?

Interesting, defining the interface hardcoded works fine, but as soon as I put a variable with the interface in it, it won't work:

```
$mgmtnet = shell_exec("/sbin/ip addr show dev eth0.1100 | /usr/bin/awk  '/global/ { $2=substr($2, 1, length($2)-7); print $2 }' ");
```

Comment: Pipes work just fine for me with `shell_exec`.

Comment: did you try my example with ip addr? using any other interface like eth0 instead of $mgmtiface should display the first three parts of its ipaddress

Comment: I'm on OS X, I don't have the `ip addr` command.

Comment: I tested `shell_exec("echo foobar | grep -o ba");` and the pipe worked.

Comment: right, seems it's the variable, not the pipe, making troubles. i updated the question

Comment: Escape variable symbol: `\$2` etc so PHP doesn't think the bash variable is a PHP variable.

Comment: tried escaping all \$2 but no effect, awk doesn't run and i get full ip addr output. escaping \$mgmtiface and i get no output at all.

Comment: @DanFromGermany `$2` isn't a possible variable name, so PHP doesn't replace it (that's why you don't have to escape it in `preg_replace`). And bash doesn't replace it because it's in single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shell_exec` returns the entire output, including the trailing newline. You need to trim that off before you substitute into the next command:

```
$mgmtiface = teim(shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/awk '$3 == 1100 {print $1}' /proc/net/vlan/config"));
$mgmtnet = trim(shell_exec("/sbin/ip addr show dev $mgmtiface | /usr/bin/awk  '/global/ { $2=substr($2, 1, length($2)-7); print $2 }' "));
```

If you know the command just returns one line of output, you can use `exec` instead of `shell_exec`. It returns the last line, without the newline, so you don't need to trim it.

Comment: its everytime the tiny bits one have to look after... thank you very much!