# Using Pipe in Shell Exec/Exec/System Commands PHP

Tags: php, bash

I have a command I am trying to run, to pull metadata from audio files dynamically in a PHP script and echo just the title. The 'strings' function pulls the file header which contains the "DISP" field, which is followed by the actual title of the file. I've tried several variations, with shell_exec, exec, `backticks`, nothing seems to run the command after the |, it returns the value of the initial command only.

```
$title = system("strings -a $temp | sed -n '/DISP/{n;p;}'", $retval);
echo $title;

$title = shell_exec("(strings -a $temp | sed -n '/DISP/{n;p;}')");
echo $title;
```

Any ideas? Safe mode is not on, I've browsed through a lot of forums and can't find a solution.

WAV Header output (**WITHOUT SED**):

```
RIFF WAVEfmt data@ 3    F b #   F   j   2   V   1   Y " q   & \ (   |   6 P A   t   o   q   3   G   C   }   n   3   #   ^   ;   s   Y   .   [ T F   L   &   N ^ g   1   4   L   5   \   >   b   n   w   6   g   G   8   c . f Q \ I #   =   -   >   >   "   *   a   [   z   & 8 l   V c y   K   q j e   S d E 6 ^   E   l | A   P   }   ; ~ ; K &   }   T   Q   N   H   (   f   3   -   c 2 ^   ^   / E S   I   a u $   O   +   >   V   S l % Q b   a   .   I # I   E C p   o   ^   G $ Z   a   !   n   8 5 )   s   3   V   ;   j   |   K   >   3   C   P L 0   j   .   u F u   >   _   G   *   x   i   d   c   e   N   %   g 8 N   #   (   D \ \ 3 d   _   V   }   C   Y o 3   T   y   " ~ Q , H   y   #   ~   M   r   R   %   y   I   .   _   q   W   ^   q   z   |   r   g   F   W   d 1 K   l   *   h   W   L   ^   ; + =   1   n   z   z   Y   T 1 t   n   [   f   A   d   Q q -   V   ? d S   & 5 G   Y   l   }   c   x   V   a   X I I   a   a z |   o   p   N   O   0   0   ~   }   O   N   0 O N   6   6   o , -   X S S   !   !   8   8   d   d   \ 5 4   t 0 0   [ I I   L   L   (   (   V   V   C   C 1 1   E   E   |   |   3 z z   + a `   . Q Q   ) . .   N   N   s A A   c b b   /   0   "   !   #   #   i   i   m % %   h   h   N   N   ! Q Q   D   E a b   S   S   e ; ;   F   F   p   p   c Y Y   D   E   i   h   &   &   M   M   [   [   | g g   g   g   9   ;   <   ;   >   >   d 5 5   | t t   8   8   c ! !   # # Y   Y   W & &   n N N   d f f   )   )   A   A   _   _   3   3   +   +   I   I   e   d   @   @   >   ?   v   v   l   l   - R Q   \   \   Q   Q   0   0   d   d v 0   0   U K K   V 0 0   u i i   E   D   Q   Q   : @ @   #   #   %   &   l   l   #   #   H   G   6   6   %   %   A   A   i q q   G   G   t   t   X 3 2   Q   Q   S   S   + 1 1   ?   @   S   S   8 1 1   l   l   L   K   2   2   _   a   D   D   t   t   8   8   y ( '   [   [   \   \   %   $   C . /   @   A   [   [   ; ; }   }   t   t   -   -   E   D   K   K   } f f   e S S   3   :   % g - H t   J : ^ i m H q + Q   =   l   i S > S t   @   N   T   p   `   Q   F   ; Q s \ j = Q   "   >   >   Y   n   5   K   +   A   ,   5   g   r   * ~ t   <   4   D   |   " H S   M e {   ( ( s i # v d ; ^   |   r   C   #   F   [   ! F H   k > @ | !   *   -   q   "   &   o # \   M # g   5 N e   @ ; { q o   w   o   o   ^   A   .   C . W   f   a   R   3   ^   F D W   c K 3   P @ E   d Q '   E - M   N   (   Y   V   I   )   h   }   n O I   @   F   z   .   T   f   A   H j ;   V a ^   x   C   c   P   [   V   5   |   ]   k   c g A   \   y   & N &   _   T   | x + I w   f   j   8   `   b   l   V   -   g   6   8   k v i   F   d   4 + \ N A   D   +   j   n   ] i f h V K D   z   ^ _ F   b } a   [   t   O   , V b   ; ( ?   A   %   0   v f c T H f n A F   $   3   T   n   ;   y   # \ } @ E c t   >   ` @ \   &   W   q N ]   c   ! ; r   @ ( 6   |   7   `   / u '   7   w   L   2   L   ^   o   @   >   |   8 = >   = W j   V   Z   % . G g 0 5 a   < V ,   q   }   V M L   m j 7   N   A C r   V C 7 } 1 A t   9   S   P m d   M   L   ? u i t V   P S z g A   d , k   &   .   $   r C O   N   % + K   P   X   H L U A U : z   U C <   .   {   I   Q b +   (   f   D   E   k 6 d   n   y   ] 0 X   S   C   T   F ( W A J   ^   8 1 A w j J "   =   d   =   D   8   [   T S g   d   K   ! 7 o   K   ^ S j I M q >   K   W   6   $   v H Q G d   9   s m g   D   A ; J   + | %   0   y   0   j   C   A   W 7 5   ? ( t   @   (   ;   c   &   H   W   T   x   v   D   l   d l Y   .   % ; . } \ I I A d   &   D   (   h   H   6   6 w 0 f f   $   >   C p P   t V #   Q   C   Y   s   A   z   _   Z   ;   #   Y o A   a   }   X 6 M ! >   # 3 . y #   M   n   p d P   A   s y &   ^   l B Z t U   m   [   o   D   B T }   @ u 9   8   y   #   =   @   | d u   I   # q b i _   j   P   j   ;   Y   1   > H s   #   M   w 5 0 } 4 N u   | o K   ,   Y   i   E   S   6   S V f F 4 # ^   l   H   n 3 "   f M t   K   8   ;   ?   x _ )   '   I H 5   K V L   9   #   0   \   $ N (   r f I   H   _   0   0 6 @   -   j   d   (   V   S   .   =   C   b   g   A   t   q P V   Q i C   v   8   t   w   g   .   A   n   %   x   s   {   Q   v   3   | M 8   | U _ . ` w @   S   N   g   ! & x   g   8   C   a   N S v   A   y   b   H u 6   Y   w   r   ;   q v q   6   t N >   h m K   ;   q Y 0 I }   -   9 ! %   h   K y N   4   ,   q   =   a   H   _   _   3   S   $ K 4 I 9   0   F q x 0 z   ]   , = l   m * 3   -   ^ F 8   y   T @ ;   \   x   3   I   t   n   >   f   y d V   A   5   9   m   .   l   n y H   $   m . H   0   C Q \   T   " ^ A   <   A   K   \   z   e   "   0   3   t   LIST INFOIART KFAL IGNR IKEY BSTM BETM BSTW BETW ISRC BFAD BPNI ISRF IMED HKST HKEN IALB IYER IGRE IBPM ITRK ICMT IENG ITCH ICOM IPUB BCPR INAM ICOP ISFT dBpoweramp Release 16.1 ISBJ IURL IEND IERG BTXR BTPO CMD1 CMD2 CMD3 ISCI DISP Livin' On a Prayer
```

Needed Output:

```
Livin' On a Prayer
```

Comment: possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733918/how-to-use-pipe-in-php-exec

Comment: Yeah I saw that post as well, but doesn't work. My example of shell_exec above is using braces.

Comment: I suggest you to post a sample of what the content of the `$temp` file could be, and the expected output corresponding to that sample.

Comment: Updated. Its a WAV file header, lots of unneeded data contained there.

Comment: Did you verify that this is a problem with pipes in general and not with your command specifically?

Comment: Good idea. That works. I'm thinking it might have to do with the single quotes in the sed command. Will try using escapeshellarg. Doesn't look to be an issue with the pipe. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @fcamp Is there a newline after the DISP field? I've generated an example WAV file with ffmpeg and the pipe you've provided works fine.

Comment: Yes, newline on the header, as far as I can see. Output in bash as them on separate lines.